# Issues with guessing game in javascript

Tags: javascript

The current issue i am having is probably a simple one for most but i seem to have issues when using functions. My goal is to have the game prompt the person for a number between 1 and 100 if the person put's in an invalid number it will alert them and ask for a new number. If the person put a number over the random number it will inform them they are to high and allow them to try again and the same if the number is to low.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Guess game</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <script>
 var guess;
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
 var answer = false;

 
  while(answer == false){
 guess = prompt("Take a stab in the dark(1 to 100)");
   wrongGuess(guess);
   checkGuess(guess);
 
 function wrongGuess(guess){
 if(guess == null){
                alert("Bye");
    prompt.close;
   }
   
   else if(guess < 0 || guess > 100 || guess == "" || guess == " "){


                alert("Write a valid number");
            }
   }
 function checkGuess(guess){
  if (guess > randomNum){
  alert("Number is to High");
   
   if (guess == randomNum){
   answer = true;
   alert("Grats Mate you hit the nail on the head");
   }
   else{
   alert("That number is to low");
   }
   }
   }
   }
   
  
   

   
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I have it were it will ask for the numbers but it does not follow the funtion rules for checking to see if the number is over the random number it will alert you if the number is outside of the range though.

Comment: One issue is you need an opening brace here: `function checkGuess(guess) {`. Formatting your code should help you spot some issues.

Comment: why do i keep overlooking that ty so much on that.

Comment: Learn how the browser's error console works. If you look at the error message the solution becomes obvious.

Comment: well juhana i am looking as the error log in google chrome and it is not helping me understand what the issue is so any advice would be amazing.

Comment: I was able to get a bit of headway with it but as of now all i can get it to do is ask for the number and alert you if you put a number outside the range of if randomNum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your game:

```
var GUESSING_GAME = function () {
var guess = null, // don't leave your variables undefined
        randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1, // -1 +1 did nothing
        answer = false;

var checkGuess = function (guess) { // you can declare functions as variables
    if (guess > randomNum) { // no need to nest conditionals here
        alert("The number is too high.");
    } else if (guess == randomNum) {
        answer = true;
        alert("Grats mate, you hit the nail on the head!");
    } else if (guess < randomNum) { // let's add an explicit condition here
        alert("The number is too low.");
    } else {
        answer = true; // see an explanation below
    }
};

while (answer == false) {
    guess = prompt("take a stab in the dark(1 to 100)"); // no need to guard against bad input here
    checkGuess(guess);
    }
}
```

Before, a player was virtually forced to guess a number in order to break from the while loop. That is why I've added the else condition which sets answer to true, hence terminates the loop. The game will stop when a player enters anything but number.

If you want to run the game by clicking on some kind of button, be sure to add the onclick attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="GUESSING_GAME()">Start the game</a>
```

Provided that your button had an id assigned, say, gamestart...

```
<a href="#" id="gamestart">Start the game</a>
```

...you could attach an onclick event this way:

```
document.getElementById("gamestart").addEventListener("click", function () {
    GUESSING_GAME();
});
```

Hope it helps!